# Whats wrong with my code in the fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have the following code for my `CategoryFragment` class:

```
public class CategoryFragment extends Fragment {

    View myFragment;

    public static CategoryFragment newInstance(){
        CategoryFragment categoryFragment = new CategoryFragment();
        return categoryFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }



    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_category,container,false);

    }
}
```

In the part where `(R.layout.fragment_category)` is, it says that it `cannot resolve symbol R`.

Comment: Where this R is comming from? you do not decalre on the variable in your code.

Comment: Clean and rebuild your project.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the **`R.java`** to your class to use the layout id of `R.layout.fragment_category`. Import the R class with something like this:

import com.your.project.R;

Change the `com.your.project` to your package name.
The package name must be the same with the package name in your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.your.project">

    ...

</manifest>
```

If after adding the R class the problem still persist, then there probably an error in your resource files. You need to check the layout, drawable, values, etc in your resources directory.